# Java Unmarshal list of objects with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, deserialization

I have XML that looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ObjectList>
  <object attributeOne="somedate" attributeTwo="false" attributeThree="id" attributeFour="true"/>
  <object attributeOne="somedate" attributeTwo="false" attributeThree="id" attributeFour="true"/>
  <object attributeOne="somedate" attributeTwo="false" attributeThree="id" attributeFour="true"/>
  <object attributeOne="somedate" attributeTwo="false" attributeThree="id" attributeFour="true"/>
  <object attributeOne="somedate" attributeTwo="false" attributeThree="id" attributeFour="true"/>
</ObjectList>
```

I have an ObjectList class that looks like the following:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ObjectList {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ObjectList")
    @XmlElement(name = "Object")
    private ArrayList<Object> ObjectList;

    public ArrayList<Object> getObjectList() {
        return ObjectList;
    }

    public void setObjectList(ArrayList<Object> objectList) {
        ObjectList = objectList;
    }
}
```

And an object class that looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Object")
public class Object {

    Date attributeOne;
    boolean attritbuteTwo;
    String attributeThree;
    boolean attributeFour;

    @XmlAttribute
    public Date getAttributeOne() {
        return attributeOne;
    }
    public void setAttributeOne(Date attributeOne) {
        this.attributeOne = attributeOne;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public boolean isAttributeTwo() {
        return attritbuteTwo;
    }
    public void setAttributeTwo(boolean attritbuteTwo) {
        this.AttributeTwo = AttributeTwo;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getAttributeThree() {
        return attributeThree;
    }
    public void setAttributeThree(String attributeThree) {
        this.attributeThree = attributeThree;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public boolean isAttributeFour() {
        return attributeFour;
    }
    public void setAttributeFour(boolean attributeFour) {
        this.attributeFour = attributeFour;
    }
}
```

When I try to unmarshal the xml into and object using this code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectList.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

RESTResponse response = getObjects();

ObjectList objects = (ObjectList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(response.getResponseBody()));
```

I get the following error:

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ObjectList"). Expected elements are <{}Object>,<{}objectList>

**EDIT:** 
I just noticed a couple problems I changed the XmlRootElement tag of my ObjectList object to @XmlRootElement(name = "ObjectList") and the XmlRootElement tag of my Object to @XmlRootElement(name = "object). I no longer get the exception, however I get and empty list of objects now.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it says expected element: `Object` or `objectList` (starting with a lowercase "o") but it reads an `ObjectList` (starting with a uppercase "O")!

Comment: You're right, I resolved that problem already (see EDIT) however, I am now getting a null objectlist back

Comment: I think it would help if you posted the updated code and (more importantly) the input XML.

Comment: I'll mark yours as the answer, because it did end up being a case issue. I got rid of the exception by fixing my case on the custom objects XmlRootElement tags. The empty list was also because I still had the XmlElement tag in the ObjectList with an uppercase O when it needed to be lowercase

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to change name of your custom class from `Object` to some other? Or ensure that correct instance of `Object` is used in `ObjectList` class

Comment: My class isn't actually named ObjectList or Object, I just used this for my example code in this question.