# How to map a list of object for JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

> NOTE:
>
> I don't need to create the java objects because I just have to check
>   some values, but I didn't find anything to unmarshal them as a generic
>   Object or a Tree or anything. Something like the JsonNode from
>   Jackson. If this is possible let me know, so I can avoid all this mess
>   with objects to map everything.

Now the problem:

I've to unmarshal a simple xml but the result is always null. I've tried different annotations but if they're not failing the result is null.

This seems to be the same case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485002/java-unmarshal-list-of-objects-with-jaxb) but using the same annotations is not working.

The xml is something like:

```
<ServiceList>
   <Service Id="1" Code="c" Name="name" ServiceRegistrationStatusID="3" CheckedRegistrationStatusID="2" />
</ServiceList>
```

and I'm unmarshalling it like this:

```
ServiceList list = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml), ServiceList.class);
```

so I've created two inner classes like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public static class ServiceList {
    private List<Service> services;

    public List<Service> getServices() { return services; }
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ServiceList")
    @XmlElement(name = "Service")
    public void setServices(List<Service> services) { this.services = services; }

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Service")
public static class Service {
    private String id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String serviceRegistrationStatusID;
    private String checkedRegistrationStatusID;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Code")
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getServiceRegistrationStatusID() {
        return serviceRegistrationStatusID;
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name = "ServiceRegistrationStatusID")
    public void setServiceRegistrationStatusID(String serviceRegistrationStatusID) {
        this.serviceRegistrationStatusID = serviceRegistrationStatusID;
    }

    public String getCheckedRegistrationStatusID() {
        return checkedRegistrationStatusID;
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name = "CheckedRegistrationStatusID")
    public void setCheckedRegistrationStatusID(String checkedRegistrationStatusID) {
        this.checkedRegistrationStatusID = checkedRegistrationStatusID;
    }

}
```

I'm unmarshalling the xml inside a static method, so I had to put the pojos as static.

Any help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to remove  `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "ServiceList")`, it should work

Comment: Simple and effective! Thanks. :)