# Java Unmarshal list of objects with a class wrapper with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

From an XQuery performed by BaseX server I get a result like that:

```
<ProtocolloList>
  <protocollo>
    <numero>1</numero>
    <data>2014-06-23</data>
    <oggetto/>
    <destinatario/>
    <operatore/>
  </protocollo>
     ...
</ProtocolloList>
```

And I need to convert this result in a List of Protocollo objects with JAXB so that I can show them with JList. Thus, following one of the discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485002/java-unmarshal-list-of-objects-with-jaxb) I've declared the following classes:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "protocollo")
public class Protocollo {

  private int numero;
  private String data;
  private String oggetto;
  private String destinatario;
  private String operatore;

  public Protocollo(String d, String o, String des, String op) {
    this.data = d;
    this.oggetto = o;
    this.destinatario = des;
    this.operatore = op;
  }

  public Protocollo() {

  }

  @XmlElement
  public int getNumero() {
      return numero;
  }

  public void setNumero(int numero) {
      this.numero = numero;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public String getData() {
      return data;
  }

  public void setData(String data) {
      this.data = data;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public String getOggetto() {
      return oggetto;
  }

  public void setOggetto(String oggetto) {
      this.oggetto = oggetto;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public String getDestinatario() {
      return destinatario;
  }

  public void setDestinatario(String destinatario) {
      this.destinatario = destinatario;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public String getOperatore() {
      return operatore;
  }

  public void setOperatore(String operatore) {
      this.operatore = operatore;
  }

}
```

and

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "ProtocolloList")
public class ProtocolloList {

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ProtocolloList")
  @XmlElement(name = "protocollo")
  private ArrayList<Protocollo> ProtocolloList;

  public ArrayList<Protocollo> getProtocolloList() {
      return ProtocolloList;
  }

  public void setProtocolloList(ArrayList<Protocollo> protocolloList) {
      ProtocolloList = protocolloList;
  }
}
```

and finally I execute the converion like that:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Protocollo.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(this.resultXML);
protocolli = (ProtocolloList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

And I keep on getting this exception:

```
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ProtocolloList"). Expected elements are <{}protocollo>
```

I suppose I'm making some mistakes with annotations.
Can you help?

Comment: What on Earth does this have to do with Swing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your use case you do not need the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation.  This is because the `ProtocolList` element corresponds to your `@XmlRootElement` annotation.  Then you need the `@XmlElement` annotation on the property to grab each of the list items.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ProtocolloList")
public class ProtocolloList {

  private ArrayList<Protocollo> ProtocolloList;

  @XmlElement(name = "protocollo")
  public ArrayList<Protocollo> getProtocolloList() {
      return ProtocolloList;
  }

}
```

**Note:**

By default you should annotate the property.  If you want to annotate the fields you should put `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class.

---

### UPDATE

You need to make sure your `JAXBContext` is aware of the root class.  You can change your `JAXBContext` creation code to be the following:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProtocolloList.class);
```

Comment: Already tried...I get the same error. I was thinking that maybe I coule make mistakes in the JAXB initializer... It should be like this, right? "JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProtocolloList.class, Protocollo.class);"

Comment: @LoryLory - Yes you should create the `JAXBContext` on the `ProtocolloList` class.

Comment: Thank you, that was really the error. Nice of yours! :)